# Multi-screen problems redux in 12.04: virtual size does not fit available size

Tags: 12.04

After a recent update, I can no longer set my multiple screens to work as they should.

I received the error: `virtual size does not fit available size`.

This problem appeared in 11.04, but the solutions do not work now. I am running 12.04 LTS Ubuntu. How can I fix it?

My system information:

Linux ------------------ 3.2.0-75-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 19:11:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"

sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e1420000-e143ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e1400000-e141ffff

lspci -vv
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Radeon HD 6350
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 

#

lshw
75: None 00.0: 10000 Monitor
  [Created at fb.71]
  Unique ID: rdCR.EY_qmtb9YY0
  Hardware Class: monitor
  Model: "Generic Monitor"
  Vendor: "Generic"

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: What GPU you have? what version of driver you're running?   Please [edit] your question and add this information...